# Как обновить копию системных переменных (environment variable)?

Tags: c#, windows

При запуске `.exe` не явно делается копия всех env vars. Для примера, есть системная переменная `MY_ENV_VAR_FOO = hello` и мой `.exe` использует эту переменную. Но скажем, нам нужно поменять значение этой переменной на `MY_ENV_VAR_FOO = hello word` (не закрывая наш `.exe`).

В чем проблема? `.exe` имеет копию системных переменных и он ничего не знает о том, что какое то из значений было изменено.

Для того, чтоб `.exe` принял новые значения нужно его переоткрыть. Это можно сделать по разному, как один из примеров можно просто закрыть и открыть его заново вручную или (у меня так) с помощью скрипта который закроет и откроет его заново. Мой `.exe` имеет логику которая знает как запустить этот скрипт который сделает перезагрузку `.exe`.

Я написал этот скрипт потому, что у меня нет прямого доступа к `.exe` и я хочу, чтоб он сам перезагружался(так как есть эта логика).

Скрипт такой

```
set MY_TARGET=C:\My_program

taskkill /IM My_program.exe /F

@echo off
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0  echo ERROR!!! & goto :exit
@echo on

timeout 10

start "" %MY_TARGET%\My_program.exe

:exit
```

Скрипт закрывает `.exe` и через 10 сек открывает его заново.

После его выполнения выглядит все так, мы обновили системную переменную, запустился скрипт, закрыл `.exe`, открыл его заново через 10 сек. и вроде как все в порядке.

Но проблема в том, что каждый новый запущеный процесс **берет копию системных переменных из процесса который его запускает**.

Как я говорил выше `.exe` имеет логику которая запускает скрипт который перегружает `.exe` и что получается, обновили переменную `.exe` ничего не знает об этом обновлении и хранит копию переменных до того как было обновление, запускает скрипт, скрипт берет копию переменных того процесса который его запустил (наш `.exe`, копия которая не обновленная), закрывает `.exe` и через 10 сек запускает его заново, при запуске `.exe` берет копию процесса который его запустил (то есть скрипт который имеет не обновленную копию) и в итоге вновь открывшейся `.exe` имеет туже копию переменных с которыми он закрылся. То есть ничего не обновилось.

Вопрос - можно ли как то обновить копию системных переменных? Может есть что то вроде `refresh_env_vars_command` команда, которую нужно добавить в скрипт между закрытием `.exe` и его открытием заново?

Comment: [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363626/reload-environment-variables-in-c-sharp-after-launch) что нашел.

Comment: добавлю свои 5 копеек: [activate_registry_changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22734043/)